# count for enum values in mysql with null results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "user"

```
user_id|Name|employment_type|gender
------------------------------------
1      |ABC |salaried       |MALE
2      |DEF |salaried       |Male
```

employment_type = enum('salaried','self_employed')

i want to count number of rows that have employment_type = salaried and self_employed.
In above example, i want result like this

```
employment_type | count
-----------------------
salaried        |2
self_employed   |0
```

But my query gives me below result

```
employment_type | count
-----------------------
salaried        |2
```

My query :

```
SELECT employment_type ,COUNT(employment_type) as "count"
FROM users WHERE user_id IN(1,2) AND employment_type IN ("salaried","self_employed") GROUP BY employment_type
```

please help me to get desired result thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve this by introducing a table where all the `employment types` reside.

```
SELECT
emp_type,
COUNT(users.employment_type) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT  "salaried" AS emp_type
    UNION 
    SELECT "self_employed"
) AS empTypeTable
LEFT JOIN users ON users.employment_type = empTypeTable.emp_type
    AND
    user_id IN (1, 2)
    AND 
    employment_type IN (
      "salaried",
      "self_employed"
     )
GROUP BY
    empTypeTable.emp_type;
```

Then with the help of `LEFT JOIN` you will get result for all the employment types.

Answer (score 0):

For this special case (a well defined number, low number of options for employment_type) you could do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(qty), employment_type FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(0) AS qty, employment_type FROM users WHERE user_id IN(1,2) AND employment_type IN ("salaried","self_employed") GROUP BY employment_type
    UNION 
    SELECT 0 AS qty, "salaried" AS employment_type 
    UNION 
    SELECT 0 AS qty, "self_employed" AS employment_type 
) t
GROUP BY employment_type ;
```

The trick is to use something like "helper tables" which consist of single select statements - join them by union and then group over the table and the single statements.